# ios 8 swift double paging like facebook paper app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working on a iOS app and I would like to build something like I saw on the Facebook Paper.
Here attached some design of what I want to achieve.
Basically, in the upper half of the screen I have a paging.
In the lower half, I would like to have another paging that corresponds to the page in the upper side.
So, when I scroll the upper side page I want to change the pages on the lower side.
So for each upper page I have several lower pages (not the same number of sub pages for each page).

Any idea how to achieve that ?
I'm thinking of using a UICollectionView but is this the best solution?
If so, how to build the lower paging system?

Thanks for any idea.

C.C.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using a UIPageViewController. It's pretty much a glove fit for what you want. You can make it so that the pages either scroll from one to the next, or use a page curl effect like iBooks (both effects are built right into the page view controller.

You could host a second page view controller on each page to do the sub-page scrolling you want. (You'd put a container view on each page where you want the sub-page to go, and then link the container view to a second page view controller with an embed segue.)